# ejb3.0 stateless @Resource property not getting read?

Tags: java, annotations, jndi

I have a stateless EJB in JBoss5.1.2 JDK6.1 setup, injecting a property as a "Resource"

## In statelessEJBbean.java

```
@Resource(name="defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment")
Integer defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment;
```

## In \src\main\resources\META-INF\ejb-jar.xml

```
 <env-entry>
   <env-entry-name>defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment</env-entry-name>
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type>
   <env-entry-value>${xyz.ejb.pxp.defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment:10}</env-entry-value>
 </env-entry>
```

## In my .properties file I've a property

```
xyz.ejb.pxp.defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment=200
```

The property value 200 is not getting set...and it is coming in as "null" value?

But, if it do a look up on the initialcontext with the full JNDI name, the value of 200 is coming up!  Am I missing any dependent JEE jar that would support annotations?

```
final Integer defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment = (Integer) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/defaultPlayEstimateAdjustment");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There is some error?

Comment: Even this EJB's postConstruct method is not getting called. If I remove the restEasy REST calls ( jars) from this EJB...both the postConstruct method is getting called and @Resource injection is working. the JAR files I removed from lib are resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.5.Final.jar
resteasy-jackson-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxb-provider-2.3.5.Final.jar

Answer (score 0):

After adding the following exclusions...EJB postConstruct did get called and the @Resource injection also worked.

```
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
```